# Custom query in Spring Repository

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I created an SQL query:

```
select name, sum(amount) from cost inner join department where department.id = department_id group by department.name;
```

The query works correctly. I have to use this working query in my spring data application as a native query, using the @Query annotation and it doesn't work.

```
@Query(value = "select name, sum(amount) from cost inner join department where department.id = department_id group by department.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List <Cost> getGroupByDepartment();
```

Is there a step that I am missing to make this query work with my spring application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 selected fields cannot position correctly in an object **Cost**.

It is necessary to select **all** fields (*) from the table **Cost** , because the resultset should fit on a `List<Cost>` or create a new object for the result with 2 fields: **name**, **sum_amount**.

**Updated.**

Maybe so:

```
@Query(value = "select name, sum(amount) from cost inner join department where department.id = department_id group by department.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List <Object[]> getGroupByDepartment();
```

And then for data processing

```
List<Object[]> resultList = yourRepository.getGroupByDepartment();
...
        for (int i = 0; i < operationList.size(); i++) {
            Object field1 = resultList.get(i)[0];
            Object field2 = resultList.get(i)[1];
            System.out.println(field1+"="+field2);
```

Better to use appropriate casting for fields:

```
        String name = (String) operationList.get(i)[0];//name
        Integer sum = (Integer) operationList.get(i)[1];//sum(amount)
```

Comment: I tried:   @Query(value = "select *, sum(amount) from cost group by department_id",  nativeQuery = true)
    List<Cost> getGroupByDepartment(); and for now I have error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'app.cost.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Do you have any idea how to solve it?